# Как сделать так, чтобы по клике на метку на Яндекс картах происходил переход по ссылке?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, javascript-events

Создаю Яндекс.карту с множеством меток которые загружаются посредством object manager из файла .json по примеру из [песочницы](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager)
Пытаюсь решить задачу, чтобы при клике на метку вместо появления балуна происходил переход по ссылке.
Поиском в Интернете удалось найти пример в котором метка формируется непосредственно в js:

```
 myPlacemark2 = new ymaps.Placemark([60.54925268141562, 40.5215751342112182], {
    // Свойства.
    hintContent: 'Подсказка',
    link: 'https://site.ru'
}, {iconLayout: "default#image",
    // Опции.
    // Своё изображение иконки метки.
    iconImageHref: 'https://site2.ru/images.png',
    // Размеры метки.
    iconImageSize: [11, 11],
    // Смещение левого верхнего угла иконки относительно
    // её "ножки" (точки привязки).
    iconImageOffset: [-5, -5]
});
// Добавляем метку на карту.
myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark2);
// Добавляем функцию обработки клика.
myPlacemark2.events.add('click', function (event) {
  location = event.get('target').properties.get('link');
});
```

По аналогии помещаю ссылку в файл .json, который принимает такой вид:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
    {"type": "Feature", "id": 1, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [60.54925268141562, 40.5215751342112182]}, "properties": {"link": "'https://site.ru'", "hintContent": "Подсказка"}, "options":{"iconLayout": "default#image","iconImageHref": "https://site2.ru/images.png","iconImageSize": [16, 25],"iconImageOffset": [-6, -8]}}
        ]
}
```

и добавляю в js строку:

```
// Добавляем функцию обработки клика.
objectManager.events.add('click', function (event) {
  location = event.get('target').properties.get('link');
});
```

К сожалению, при клике на метку перехода не происходит. Прошу помощи, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вы попросту получаете ссылку из json. А надо дать команду на переход по ссылке. Добавьте после строчки с получением ссылки `window.location.href = location;` . К слову, вы не объявили переменную `location`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! К сожалению, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Если я вставляю `alert("location-" + location);` перед `location = event.get('target').properties.get('link');` то при клике на метку всплывает сообщение `location-undefined`.
А если после, то ничего не происходит.

Comment: Я же вам сказал, у вас `location` не определена.  Поэтому у вас в первом случае выводится `undefined`, поскольку вы ее не определили, а во втором случае не выводится, поскольку происходит ошибка присвоения не определенной переменной значения. Должно быть `let location = event.get('target').properties.get('link');`, а не `location = event.get('target').properties.get('link');`

Comment: К сожалению, не работает. Теперь, даже `alert("location-" + location);` перед `let...` не срабатывает...

Comment: Если убрать переменную из alert: `alert("location-");` тогда срабатывает. Но после строки `let location = event.get('target').properties.get('link');` все равно, нет.

Answer (score 0):

Работа с объектами менеджера описана в [документации](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/ObjectManager.html#field_detail__objects) и в [песочнице Яндекса](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/om_balloon_ajax).

Определяйте кликнутый объект по его **id**, затем уже выцепляйте его **properties**.

```
objectManager.objects.events.add('click', function (e) {
    // Получим объект, на котором открылся балун.
    var id = e.get('objectId')
    var geoObject = objectManager.objects.getById(id);
    //window.location.href = geoObject.properties.link; // в текущем окне
    window.open(geoObject.properties.link); // в новом окне
});
```

Пример на JSBIN: https://jsbin.com/qukapol/1/edit?js,output